# Is using the ASP.NET Membership providers in winforms application a bad idea?

Tags: .net, winforms

Can anyone think of a reason not use the ASP.NET membership providers in a winforms 
application?

Has anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ASP.NET membership providers on a client in a WinForms application is insecure, since a malicious user can replace the provider by one of his own choosing simply by editing the application configuration file.

What exactly are you trying to achieve, and is security important?

Comment: Go with AD security and Windows principle if you can, since that will can be secured at thread-level. As Joe said, ASP.NET Membership only locks the front-door.

Comment: I came across this article :http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2006/01/15/81140.aspx . Security is important,in addition to the fact that I like the built in security and role membership model provided by ASP,Net

Comment: "I came across this article". Yes, you can use Membership in a WinForms application as described in the article.  But it doesn't give you security.