# How could I setup users in Membership Services from a Desktop application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

This is odd, but we have written an asp.Net web application (all's well there) but now we are importing a large amount of data, and in this case, users with existing usernames and passwords.  The import is being done with a desktop application.

I need to take each user from the old system, and create a corresponding user in the new system, and to do that I need to add each of them to asp.net membership services.

I'm at a complete loss as to how I can do this from the desktop.  I mean, I've got references to System.Web.Security, but what would I put in my App.config?

I'm sorry, I don't think I fully understand Membership Services enough to phrase this question all that well.  But can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check following SO threads for more information :

[Can you use the asp.net membership provider in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application)

[Is using the ASP.NET Membership providers in winforms application a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002645/is-using-the-asp-net-membership-providers-in-winforms-application-a-bad-idea)

Comment: The answer is "Yes", very easily.  I'm not using it for security on my desktop app, merely using a desktop app to pre-populate the database with web users.