# Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are []

Tags: wcf, asp.net-membership

it's my first try to make a WCF service that uses Asp.Net Membership provider for Authentication , what i try to do is very simple :
1- The default Asp web app where users will register and create accounts (using Asp.Net Membership provider)
2- WCF service that can be used only by the members registered

so i tried this example : [Configuring an ASP.NET Application to Use Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx)

I created a default Asp web app, Membership works fine.
**My problem is configuring the WCF App.Config :**
So please guys correct me if I'm wrong
1- is it the right example (cause i want to use that WCF service later for Asp.Net Membership Authentication from Winform App, everybody say don't use it from the winform, it's not secure use WCF Service)
2- if yes, correct me here : what i need to put in the App.Config of the WCF is

1. **Connectionstring** : pointing to the ASPNETDB.MDF database base file where the users are saved
2. **Membership/Profiles/Roles Provider**
3. **Behavior**
4. **Bindings** : wsHttpBinding

3- If by miracle i'm right until here, this is my App.Config File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>

        <!--_______________________________________ Connection String-->
        <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices"
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=E:\DOCUMENTS\CODE\WCFwsHttpBindingTest\WebAppWsHttpBinding\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <!--_________________________________________ Provider-->
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                        connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
                        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
                        enablePasswordReset="true" 
                        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
                        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
                        minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
      </system.web>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" 
                   name="WCFwsHttpBinding.Service1">


            <endpoint address ="" 
                      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="MembershipBinding"
                      name="ASPmemberUserName"
                      contract="WCFwsHttpBinding.IService1">
            </endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>

        <!--__________________________________________ Behavior-->
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
              <serviceCredentials>
                <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
              </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <!--__________________________________________ Binding-->
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MembershipBinding">
              <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

      </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

when i try debug, i get this Error:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].
```

*Thank you so much for helping.*

Comment: First of all, from where do you expose your WCF service ? From IIS or from a windows Service ? What is the goal of your service ? Managing the user rights or authenticate users which are connecting to your service ?

Comment: Sorry i'm Beginner :( , give minutes, I'll see what that means !

Comment: @RomEh : i want to use this WCF service for authentication, my problem is exactly this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002645/is-using-the-asp-net-membership-providers-in-winforms-application-a-bad-idea

Comment: @RomEh They say, you need to use a Web service (WCF in my case) for authentication, so i was following that path, and the closest example i found to what i want to do is here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406125.aspx it's the 2nd part of the tutorial : "Control Access to and Usage of Public Web-Hosted Services" so i to answer your question : i think it's IIS hosting Right !!! (please if you have better idea tell me)